# numpy insert seems to be replacing

Tags: python

I am trying to write a simple program that adds some lines to a file. To do this I am using numpy insert. For some reason, this seems to be replacing a row rather than inserting one. what am I doing wrong?

current code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

#import the csv file
file = np.loadtxt("name.csv", skiprows=1, dtype='<U70', delimiter =',')
#get row and col count
fileShape = file.shape
rows = fileShape[0]
cols = fileShape[1]

#iterate over array
for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        #the only column that matters to me is the 5th one of my csv
        #also blocking overflow with the row check
        if (col == 4 and row + 1 < rows):
            #if the current row does not equal the next row
            #then I want to insert a row to do some things in Excel with
            if (link[row][col] != link[row+1][col]):
                #grab the next row and store it
                temp = file[row+1]
                #replace the 6th column with nothing
                temp[5] = ""
                #insert the new row into the array
                np.insert(file, row, [temp], 0)

outfile = pd.DataFrame(file)
outfile.to_csv("OutFile.csv")
```

this takes in a file that roughly looks like the blow:

```
ccType,number,date,payee,total,indAmt,memo,catagory
mastercard,30,11/21/2022,Bluejam,287.24,44.33,,Sports
mastercard,30,11/23/2022,Fanoodle,287.24,95.95,,Health
mastercard,30,11/25/2022,Eazzy,287.24,1.2,,Automotive
mastercard,30,11/26/2022,Dabfeed,287.24,68.97,,Games
mastercard,30,11/30/2022,Jaloo,287.24,76.79,,Games
mastercard,50,7/4/2023,Shufflebeat,317.13,91.91,,Sports
mastercard,50,7/4/2023,Meembee,317.13,94.69,,Toys
mastercard,50,7/5/2023,Jabberbean,317.13,67.01,,Computers
mastercard,50,7/28/2023,Wikibox,317.13,33.18,,Movies
mastercard,50,7/29/2023,Shufflebeat,317.13,30.34,,Automotive
```

I am getting a result like this:

```
ccType,number,date,payee,total,indAmt,memo,catagory
mastercard,30,11/21/2022,Bluejam,287.24,44.33,,Sports
mastercard,30,11/23/2022,Fanoodle,287.24,95.95,,Health
mastercard,30,11/25/2022,Eazzy,287.24,1.2,,Automotive
mastercard,30,11/26/2022,Dabfeed,287.24,68.97,,Games
mastercard,30,11/30/2022,Jaloo,287.24,76.79,,Games
mastercard,50,7/4/2023,Shufflebeat,317.13,,,Sports
mastercard,50,7/4/2023,Meembee,317.13,94.69,,Toys
mastercard,50,7/5/2023,Jabberbean,317.13,67.01,,Computers
mastercard,50,7/28/2023,Wikibox,317.13,33.18,,Movies
mastercard,50,7/29/2023,Shufflebeat,317.13,30.34,,Automotive
```

note how the "mastercard,50,7/4/2023,Shufflebeat,317.13,,,Sports" replaced the 6th row of the original instead of inserting at that row. the "new" csv should have been 11 rows not 10.

Comment: People usually use `pd.read_csv()` to read CSV files. This gives a number of nice features, such as automatically detecting the name and data type of each column.

Comment: Note that `np.insert()` does not operate in place: it returns a copy of the array with the element added, rather than modifying the array you pass. Documentation: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.insert.html

Comment: On the line `temp = file[row+1]`, I believe this is creating a view of the array. So when the `temp[5] = ""` line runs, it is modifying the original `file` array. I think the intent here is to make a copy rather than a view. You can do that with `temp = file[row+1].copy()`

Comment: pandas and numpy, both enormous packages, are totally unnecessary overkill for this problem.  You have a simple text-based process.  Use the `csv` module and you can remain in complete control of the processing.

Comment: @TimRoberts There is zero reason to reinvent the wheel. Importing numpy to use `loadtxt` instead of a dumb manual approach with a bunch of splits is better in every single way, unless you're embedding your code in a satellite and want to save space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem:** `np.insert` does not modify the array in place; instead, it returns a new array.

Please use following:

```
temp = file[row+1].copy()  # use copy to avoid modifying the original array
temp[5] = ""
file = np.insert(file, row+1, [temp], axis=0) # insert the new row into the array
```

Your code with updates:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

file = np.loadtxt("name.csv", skiprows=1, dtype='<U70', delimiter =',')
fileShape = file.shape
rows = fileShape[0]
cols = fileShape[1]

for row in range(rows):
    for col in range(cols):
        if (col == 4 and row + 1 < rows):
            if (file[row][col] != file[row+1][col]):
                temp = file[row+1].copy()  # use copy to avoid modifying the original array
                temp[5] = ""
                file = np.insert(file, row+1, [temp], axis=0) # insert the new row into the array

outfile = pd.DataFrame(file)
outfile.to_csv("OutFile.csv")
```

Output:

```
,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7
0,mastercard,30,11/21/2022,Bluejam,287.24,44.33,,Sports
1,mastercard,30,11/23/2022,Fanoodle,287.24,95.95,,Health
2,mastercard,30,11/25/2022,Eazzy,287.24,1.2,,Automotive
3,mastercard,30,11/26/2022,Dabfeed,287.24,68.97,,Games
4,mastercard,30,11/30/2022,Jaloo,287.24,76.79,,Games
5,mastercard,50,7/4/2023,Shufflebeat,317.13,,,Sports
6,mastercard,50,7/4/2023,Shufflebeat,317.13,91.91,,Sports
7,mastercard,50,7/4/2023,Meembee,317.13,94.69,,Toys
8,mastercard,50,7/5/2023,Jabberbean,317.13,67.01,,Computers
9,mastercard,50,7/28/2023,Wikibox,317.13,33.18,,Movies
10,mastercard,50,7/29/2023,Shufflebeat,317.13,30.34,,Automotive
```

Comment: I knew it was going to be a silly mistake :). Thanks